# retrieve FoxPro 7.0 database schema

Tags: schema, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I need to obtain a list of tables in a Visual Fox Pro database. (7.0)  This is what I'm doing.... but it's not working or I'm not doing it right...

```
DataFactory dataFactory = new DataFactory();

dataFactory.CreateOldStarbaseConnection();
dataFactory.OpenOldStarbaseConnection();
OleDbConnection oldStarbaseConnection = dataFactory.OldStarbaseConnection;

object[] arrRestrict = new object[] { null, null, "NewStarbase", null };

// Get the tables in the new Database
DataTable tblDbSchema = newStarbaseConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, arrRestrict);

// for each table in the new database
foreach (DataRow myDataRow in tblDbSchema.Rows)
{}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently wrote a code generation application for [LINQ to VFP](http://linqtovfp.codeplex.com/) that gets the schema information.  Here is how I got the schema.

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
    conn.Open();
    DataTable tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
    DataTable columns = conn.GetSchema("Columns");
    DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("Indexes");
    conn.Close();
}
```